# Noob needs advise on three tables in postgresql DB

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I've very minor experience at working with databases( I only know the absolute basics). With that stated I guess my problem is rather easy to solve for more experienced minds.

My question is:

I need a way to be able to search for example "all types of Aluminium and all its sub_materials"?

I can do simple queries like

```
SELECT * 
FROM sub_materials 
WHERE category_id = 2;
```

So what I'm asking for is basically to be able to see the whole branch of Aluminium. I've looked at `ltree`and `Closure Tables` But I'm to much of a Noob to figure it out by my self.

I believe I have to connect the tables somehow as "grandparent, parent, child" or something similar, but I've no idea if there is some other way or?

I'm not even sure if I'm doing this the right way.
Can someone advise me on this?

I've three tables in a database.(below are samples from the tables)

1. `materials_category` Holds all the categories for every material in the DB.
2. `materials` Holds the Category name and id, material_names and ids and the values for each material.

Some materials has sub_categories. not all but some.
3. `sub_materials` Holds the category info, material name and id, the sub_material name and id and the sub_material values.

```
1. `materials_category`

 |category_id| category_name|
------------------------------
 |    1      | Aggregate    |
 |    2      | Aluminium    |
 |    3      | Asphalt      |


2. `materials`
    |category_id |category_name |material_id |material_name|EE_1|EE_2|EC_1|EC_2
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | 1          |Aggregate     | 1          | General     |3   |0   | 52 | 8
    | 2          |Aluminium     | 2          | General     |55  |7   |  9 | 24
    | 2          |Aluminium     | 3          | Cast Pr     |34  |30  | 22 | 28
    | 2          |Aluminium     | 4          | Extrud.     |65  |16  |  8 | 74
    | 2          |Aluminium     | 5          | Rolled      |15  | 0  |  9 | 61
    | 3          |Asphalt       | 6          |Asphalt, 4%  |2   |22  | 6  | 54
    | 3          |Asphalt       | 7          |Asphalt, 5%  |3   |91  |  1 | 4

3. `sub_materials`

|category_id|category_name|material_id|material_name|sub_mar_id|sub_mar_name|EE_1|EE_2|EC_1|EC_2|   
|2          |Aluminium    |2          |General      |1         |Virgin      |21  |5   |9   |60  |   
|2          |Aluminium    |2          |General      |2         |Recycled    |29  |3   |8   |9   |
```

Comment: ...which is it, mysql or postgresql (they're two very different products, although might not matter here)?  What is the final set of data you want to retrieve?  (And the non-normalized data irks me, but that may not be something you can change)

Comment: Hi @Clockwork-Muse it's postgresql I'm using.  what I need is to be able to search for "aluminium" and than I can see all the types of "aluminium" and the sub_materials that belongs to "aluminium" for example.

Comment: If you would provide an example of the output you want, rather than just a description, it would be helpful.

Comment: @Brian I'm not sure how to show the output I want,  but lets say... I need to see the `EC_1` value for ` Extrud` `Aluminium`   (category_id 2, material_id 4) but because ` Extrud` `Aluminium` has `sub_material` I would like to be able to see the `sub_materials`that belong to ` Extrud` `Aluminium` and the `EC_1` value for that also

Comment: Your output is going to be a table, isn't it?  Draw it out the way you've drawn your input tables.  That's the "how to show the output".  However, where in your sample data is the link that says 'Extrud' Aluminium has a sub_material?  'Extrud' has a material_id of 4, which doesn't appear in the sub_materials table.

Answer (score 0):

Your tables are denormalised. This is usually not a good thing, unless this is a reporting only database.

Anyway, here's a start for what you're after. why don't you run it and give some feedback on whether it's what you  want or not.

```
select *
from materials_category c
left outer join materials m
on c.category_id = m.category_id
left outer join sub_materials s
on s.material_id = m.material_id
where c.category_name = 'Aluminium'
```

Looking at your data, I'm guessing that 'recycled' could apply to any number of material categories, not just Aluminium? Would you have a whole bunch of 'Recycled' records in your sub_materials to allow for each material_category?

Comment: Thanks @Nick.McDermaid this is helpful, Yes this is something like what I need, I can see that the DB needs some normalisation. `Recycled`and `virgin` applies to many materials in the `sub_materials` table. I have to take a closer look at this tomorrow morning.